# Css, i want to blurr the border without blurring the content of a div

Tags: html, css, css-filters

Html code

```
<div style="display: inline" class="button">    <a href="indeks.html">Home</a> </div>
```

Css code

```
.button {
border : 2px solid white ;
-webkit-filter: blur(3px);}
```

The thing is that i want to blurr that border without blurring the text in href. 
I tried finding it on the web but there is nothing similar (ppl maynly ask how to blur onlt the part of an image) .
I also tried screwing with z-index but it gave no effect (added another class for hrref without the blurr and put it above but it seems to inherit the property).

Im just out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Blurry border...* Well, I'd go with [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) rather than [CSS filter effects](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/):

```css
box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px gray, inset 0 0 8px gray;
```

Here is the demo:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block; padding: .4em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px gray, inset 0 0 8px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="indeks.html">Home</a>
</div>
```